# How to add data into a table using a model - HTML

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to allow a user to add data to a table by selecting the "New" button.  I was hoping to accomplish this using html only, if possible.

Here's what I have:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="targetModal">New</button>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Game</th>
    <tr>
    <thead>
<table>

<div class="modal" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5> Please enter the following information </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
```

Not sure here- I know it'll be an input field, but how can I link this to when the
user selects 'Submit' it takes these input fields and then adds a new row under the table with those inputs?
So for example like ID: *user types* 123   etc, then under ID: it'll have 123 when I hit submit.

```
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button">Submit</button>
               <button type="button">Cancel</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I apologize if I left any thing obvious out.  I wasn't in a spot to copy and paste this so I wrote it by memory.  If you do need more information I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need javascript

Comment: Dang, alrighty...Thanks B001!